# How can I have helm post upgrade hooks not cause the entire install to fail?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to run a `helm install` and a post-install hook is error'ing out. But I don't want it to fail the entire deployment for that reason, I want to know about it and fix the issue but I need all of the other parts of the chart to succeed. Is there a way to just ignore just the post-hook errors? Or downgrade them to warnings?

Comment: I think it will work to `helm upgrade` the same chart with the same values.  Since this is an "upgrade" and not an "install" the post-install hooks won't try to run, and once the "upgrade" has run successfully the chart will be in an "installed" state.

Comment: In practice, by the time any of the post-* hooks have run, the chart is already fully deployed (the Deployments, Services, _etc._ all exist and the cluster should be creating Pods) and your system may be operational anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at this more, I don't think I actually want to ignore the post upgrade hook failure. I just need to ensure that the pod that is failing is not failing for unexpected reasons during the post-upgrade hook phase.